# Using categoryId as a search filter in Foursquare "Das-Quadrat" iOS API wrapper

Tags: ios, swift, search, foursquare, swifty-json

I'm writing an app for iOS where I'm searching for venues with a specific [categoryId](https://developer.foursquare.com/categorytree), rather than a search query. My app does not require users to sign in, so I'm using a third party API Wrapper called [das-quadrat](https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/das-quadrat) to skip the hassle of OAuth with users. **I'm following the search request example towards the bottom of the page.**

In addition, this is how they implement their functionality in their demo project (ExploreViewController.swift):

```
func exploreVenues() {

    let location = self.locationManager.location
    var parameters = location.parameters()
    let task = self.session.venues.explore(parameters) {
        (result) -> Void in
        if self.venueItems != nil {
            return
        }
        if !NSThread.isMainThread() {
            fatalError("!!!")
        }

        if result.response != nil {
            if let groups = result.response!["groups"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]  {
                var venues = [[String: AnyObject]]()
                for group in groups {
                    if let items = group["items"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                        venues += items
                    }
                }

                self.venueItems = venues
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else if result.error != nil && !result.isCancelled() {
            self.showErrorAlert(result.error!)
        }
    }
    task.start()
}
```

In my own code, I've got an array of some relevant categoryIds, and I want to perform a search task for each of them. Here I'm attempting to search for categoryIds, then storing the name of the venue and the distance from the user in a dictionary (using SwiftyJSON - I would link but I don't have enough reputation yet) to get elements from the JSON:

```
var venues: [JSONParameters]!
var distance: [JSONParameters]!
var session : Session!

let tagData = TagData() 
/* 
TagData contains a dictionary with relevant categoryIDs and the number 
of times the user has visited that venue.
*/

var categoryTagSearch: [String] = TagData.returnRelevantCategories()

var venueNamesDictionary: [String: Int] = [:] //name : distance from user

func findVenues(callback: [String: Int] -> Void)  {

    for tag in categoryTagSearch {

        let searchTask = session.venues.search(tag) {
            (result) -> Void in

            if let response = result.response { //trying to create keys of names with values of distances
                let count: Int? = response["venues"].array?.count
                let venueName: [String] = response["venues"]["name"].arrayValue
                let distanceValue: [Int] = response["venues"]["location"]["distance"].arrayValue

                for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    venueNamesDictionary[venueName[i]] = distanceValue[i]
                }        
            }
        } // end searchtask assignment

        callback(searchTask.start()) //to force this to wait for responses to finish filling Dictionary

    }// end for

}// end Function
```

The problem is that searching for a categoryId rarely returns search results; it's akin to putting "4bf58dd8d48988d1c8941735" in the search bar of Foursquare, which will either not return venues of the correct category or anything at all. **How do I ensure that my search only returns venues of the correct category? Is there a function I'm overlooking?**

Answer (score 1):

Do you really specify the category? To specify a category, do the following.

```
var parameters = [Parameter.categoryId:"4bf58dd8d48988d1c8941735"]
currentTask = session.venues.search(parameters) {
```